# 3d-Model loading via Three.js

Tags: three.js, 3d, gltf

I have started getting into Three.js and have gotten stuck with loading gltf-files. I have managed to fix all errors, but my model still does not show up on my page. This is my code:

```
function init() {

        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);

        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);


        let controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

        /*
        let geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
        let material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00, wireframe: true } );
        cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        scene.add( cube );*/

        var loader = new GLTFLoader();

        loader.load(
            // resource URL
            'models/eevee/eevee.gltf',
            // called when the resource is loaded
            function ( gltf ) {

                let object = gltf.scene.children[0];
                object.scale.set(0.1,0.1,0.1);
                object.position.set(0, -10, -0.75);

                scene.add( object );

                renderer.render(scene, camera);

            },
            // called while loading is progressing
            function ( xhr ) {

                console.log( ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );

            },
            // called when loading has errors
            function ( error ) {

                console.log( 'An error happened' );
                console.log(error)

            }
        );

        camera.position.z = 5;

        window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize);

    }
```

As I said, no error shows up, but the 3d model does not get displayed on my page.

Comment: Any errors in the console? Sometimes the loaded model is too gigantic and is outside of the range of the camera, or sometimes too small to be visible...

Comment: It could be helpful if you include context data, like browser, OS and specs

Comment: [this article](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-load-obj.html) might suggest some ideas

Comment: @gman 
I have tried to use this tutorial, but i get an error saying "Cannot read property 'getUniforms' of undefined".

Answer (score 1):

It works fine for me, I just add an Ambiant Light, setting the camera position and add "THREE" to : `var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();`

```
function init() {
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);

    light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff); 
    scene.add(light);

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 100000);
    camera.position.set(150, 180, 280);

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    let controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

    var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();

    loader.load(
        'assets/models/gltf/street_car.glb',
        function ( gltf ) {
            let object = gltf.scene.children[0];
            object.scale.set(100,100,100);
            object.position.set(0, 0, 0);
            scene.add( object );
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        },
        function ( xhr ) {
            console.log( ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );
        },
        function ( error ) {
            console.log( 'An error happened' );
            console.log(error)
        }
    );
    camera.position.z = 5;
    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize);
}

init();
```

Comment: Do you have any idea what the problem could be? Maybe a corrupted file?
Additionally, I don't see any changes when changing the color of the light. Should there be a difference when no model is loaded?

Comment: Maybe your gltf file is not good. Try to load it here : https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/
If he's good, you can try to load in my three.js scene : https://sboez.github.io/3D-Models-Load/
You can inspire you to my code if you want or just take my .glb models to load them in your scene.

For the light it was just to  be sure that scene is enlightened.

Comment: I tried loading my model here: https://sboez.github.io/3D-Models-Load/ and it worked, but my model was black and there was no lighting.
On this website:  gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com   my model loaded correctly and i was able to see it. This time it was white and the lighting worked.

Comment: Yes, it's normal. I did not manage the material for gltf model in my work. So, your model is ok :) did you see it with your code ? If you didn't, try to rescale your model with big numbers. In my repo, gltf files are : object.scale.set(100,100,100);

Comment: I have tried scaling it to 0.1 and 100, no changes. When i open it in Blender the model is very big. Do you have any ideas what else could be wrong?

Comment: Hum, not really, it could be just bad camera position... Did you copy/paste the code above ? Because it works for me, so it should works for you too.

Comment: I'll give it a try when I am at home, but thank you in advance

Comment: Well, I just have it a try and nothing changed. I don't know what's wrong. 
These are the two scripts I have in my index.html:  


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/110/three.min.js"></script>  
<script src="js/main.js" type="module"></script>  

And in my main.js I have  

import {OrbitControls} from '../three.js-master/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';  
import {WEBGL} from "../three.js-master/examples/jsm/WebGL.js";  
import {GLTFLoader} from "../three.js-master/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js";  

could this cause a problem?

Comment: Damn I am sorry for that formatting. It doesn't really seem to work

Comment: Did you push your code in github ? Or use an online IDE, then I'll be able to watching.

Comment: Ok, so just delete camera.position.z = 5; line 46

Comment: still not visible :/

Comment: I sent you a pull request ;-)

Comment: damn thanks dude, after a week its finally solved :D